# Reversing a list without using append()

Tags: python, list, reverse

I don't know why I'm getting an error with the following code:

```py
def reverse(lis):
    a = []
    for i in lis[::-1]:
        a+=i
    return a
print(reverse([1,2,3]))
```

If I use the `append()` method, then it gives the correct answer. However, I'm looking for an approach that doesn't use `append()`.

Comment: You should only include the tags that actually describe your problem. You should only really have the `python` tag.

Comment: Please don't spam-tag inappropriate tags. It can be quite annoying to come to a question tagged [tag:java], and to find that it has nothing to do with Java programming, and this can lead to down-votes and close-votes. I will edit your tags now, but in the future, please take care to do this yourself.

Comment: Note that since you're already using `lis[::-1]` you could just make the entire function `return lis[::-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *really* close. `+=` performs the addition operation between an integer and a list, which isn't defined.

Instead, you should use `+=` with a singleton list that contains the element:

```py
def reverse(lis):
    a = []
    for i in lis[::-1]:
        a += [i]
    return a
print(reverse([1,2,3])) # Prints [3, 2, 1]
```